# Problem with Yoast canonical with staging site

Tags: yoast

My GF is running a wordpress site with Yoast. We are having a problem with self-referential canonical tag rel=canonical, which Yoast appears to add to all pages.

The problem is that she uses a staging site for writing and development, the  she promotes the staging to the production site. When creating a post, Yoast is adding rel=canonical which points to the post at staging.thedomain.com. When she promotes to the live site (thedomain.com), the canonical tag is unchanged, and points to the article on the staging site, which causes lots of problems.

How can I configure Yoast on the staging site to always create canonicals pointing to https://thedomain.com/post rather than https://staging.thedomain.com/post
???

This solution needs to work for all pages, not just posts, obviously.

Thank you so much. I’ve read the docs at Yoast and it mentions a wpseo_canonical filter but no instructions on how to do this.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

You have this filter: apply_filters( 'wpseo_canonical', $canonical ); where $canonical is the string you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue. I found a solution on SO https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/368601/20374
I've been doing `wp yoast index` on the command line, your other option is to install Yoast Test Helper plugin.

I don't know of a Yoast configuration for Canonical setting site wide, but you can do it per post, if you open the settings in the post/page and toggle "advanced".